# CSS and JS files work for admin but not for members and visitors-SP 2013

Tags: 2013

I have css and js files. They work fine when I access with admin acount but when I access with member and visitor acounts, these files don't work.

How can I solve it and why does it happen?

Comment: Where are the files located?

Comment: In Style library

Comment: Check the permissions on Style Library. It's most likely a permission issue.

Comment: I checked them but didn't find anything they have permission to view the style library folders. :/ I can't find any clue in web too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to publish all the files as a major version.

Comment: how can i do it? I couldn't find

Comment: select the file and check the option in the ribbon under documents.

Comment: It says this control is currently disabled.

Comment: Please mark the right answer.

Comment: @e.ozmen mark the answer right